# How to add library to forked cdnjs repo?

Tags: git, github, fork

i follow [add or update library to cdnjs](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs). I've just forked cdnjs repo to my own GitHub account.

In above tutorial there is a line: 
`"When you have forked the cdnjs repo, add your library to it."`. How to add my library to it? How to create a new folder in ajax/libs?

I cloned cdnjs repo (94 000 files, ~ 500MB) to my computer using GitHub desktop application. Was it necessary? I do not need all libraries.

All i want to do is upload to cdnjs my own folder with my own js library. **How to do this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a file in cdnjs repo root, that is named CONTRIBUTING.
All necessary information about contributing to cdnjs can be found in this [file](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md). It contains lots of guidelines you have to take care of!!

To create a new folder, just enter your forked and downloaded repository and create a new one in ajax/libs. Your library shall be in this newly created dir.

If you want to commit your library, your master has to be up to date and all other libraries have to be in your commit as well. Otherwise you would delete all other libraries from Githubs cdnjs master.
If you finished adding your library, create a pull request and wait for it to be accepted.